# Como mudar o valor da chave em um dicionário em Python?

Tags: python

Existem algum método em Python que **altere o nome da chave do dicionário**? eu apenas conheço como mudar o valor.

```
Exemplo:
RE2 =   {
       "Nome": "Leon Scott Kennedy",
       "Ocupação": "Oficial de Polícia (R.P.D)",
       "Nascimento": 1977
       }

print (RE2)
```

Eu queria mudar a chave **Nascimento** para **Data de Nascimento**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `del` para remover apos colocar o valor em uma nova `key` ficando +/- assim:

```
RE2 =   {
   "Nome": "Leon Scott Kennedy",
   "Ocupação": "Oficial de Polícia (R.P.D)",
   "Nascimento": 1977
}

RE2["Data de Nascimento"] = RE2["Nascimento"]
#    ^ key nova                  ^ key antiga

del RE2["Nascimento"]
#        ^ delete key antiga

print(RE2)
```

<sup>[Exemplo online](https://ideone.com/wAOnU5)</sup>

---

Você também pode utilizar o método `pop` para isso ficando +/- assim:

```
RE2 =   {
   "Nome": "Leon Scott Kennedy",
   "Ocupação": "Oficial de Polícia (R.P.D)",
   "Nascimento": 1977
}

RE2["Data de Nascimento"] = RE2.pop("Nascimento")
#    ^ key nova                      ^ key antiga
print(RE2)
```

<sup>[Exemplo online 2](https://ideone.com/f2Cm1w)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 9):

Não existe o rename, mas é possível guardar o valor em uma nova chave e apagar a antiga numa única operação se for usado o método `pop` dos dicionários:

```
RE2["Data de Nascimento"] = RE2.pop("Nascimento")
```

Isso economiza uma linha, e a necessidade do `del`. Além disso o `pop` permite que se coloque um argumento padrão - assim, se por acaso a chave antiga não estiver definida, você não terá um erro - em vez disso, o valor padrão é usado:

```
RE2["Data de Nascimento"] = RE2.pop("Nascimento", "")
```

Vai criar a entrada `"Data de Nascimento"` com o valor `""` (string vazia), se não havia uma chave "`Nascimento`" no dicionário original.

Se for uma operação que você vai fazer muitas vezes, pode ser mais elegante (mas nem sempre), criar uma classe que extenda os dicionários originais do Python e acrescente um método que faça isso. Internamente, a melhor forma ainda vai ser o uso do `pop` e criação da nova chave - mas o seu dicionário pode passar a ter um método "rename" que faça isso:

```
class MeuDict(dict):
   def rename(self, old_key, new_key):
        self[new_key] = self.pop(old_key)
```

E isso pode ser usado diretamente, bastando que seu objeto original seja dessa nova classe. Como os dicionários normais de Python aceitam dicionários como parâmetros para inicialização, um dicionário normal pode ser convertido neste simplestemente com:

```
RE2 = MeuDict(RE2)
```

e então:

```
RE2.rename("Nascimento", "Data de nascimento")
```

Se for usar esse código em produção "pra valer", ou seja, precisar de algo confiável, com mais funcionalidades, pode aproveitar que a lógica fica toda num lugar, e tornar o código "thread safe" - isso é, no caso de um programa com várias threads, tornar o rename uma operação "atômica" - com o uso de um lock - isso evita uma chance de o valor que está sendo renomeado não estar nem em uma chave nem em outra em um dado momento.

Também podemos usar a ["sentinel pattern"](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/) para repetir no método `rename`
o comportamento do parâmetro `default` do pop.

```
import threading
_sentinel = object()

class MeuDict(dict):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       self.lock = threading.Lock()
       super().__init__(*args, **kw)

   def rename(self, old_key, new_key, default=_sentinel):
        pop_sentinel = {} if default is _sentinel else {'default': default}
        with self.lock:
             # cria a nova chave -  entre essa linha e a próxima as
             # duas chaves existem. Se a thread mudar bem nesse ponto, o valor
             # vai ser encontrado nas duas - o que é melhor 
             # que "em nenhuma", que acontece com o `pop`
             self[new_key] = self.get(old_key, **pop_sentinel)
             del old_key
```

## Se uma operação atômica for realmente necessária

Depois de responder, me dei conta que o `threading.Lock` sozinho só impede que o mesmo lock seja usado em outra thread - ainda haveria o risco de numa segunda thread algum código "olhar" o dicionário entre as duas modificiações de chave. Por isso mudei do código do `pop` para o cópia + del - as duas chaves existirão nesse tempo de transição.

Se você realmente precisa de um objeto thread-safe que não permita nenhuma race-condition em que o dicionário seja "visto" sem nenhuma ou sem duas chaves, a única forma é aumentar a especialização da classe - tem-se que criar um "mapping" (um objeto como um dicionário), que use o locking da thread em todos os pontos em que um item do dicionário for ser consultado - aí, usando o mesmo lock, ele vai ter que aguardar o final da atualização antes de disponibilizar a consulta. Nesse caso, não vale a pena herdar de um dicionário (dict) - que por conta de otimizações internas, não tem um único ponto de consulta das chaves e valores, e sim, herdar de `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, implementar o `rename` como acima, e, dntro do `__getitem__`, `__iter__` e `__delitem__` fazer também uso do mesmo lock.

A maior diferença é que o collections.abc.MutableMapping permite que você implemente um objeto que funcione como um dicionário, mas ele mesmo não é um dicionário - no caso de herdar de `dict`, manipulamos as chaves nos métodos usando o `self`. Nessa outra implementação, a recomendação é manter um dicionário interno, num atributo privado.

Comment: não era necessário explicar tão detalhadamente a ponto de ter importado uma biblioteca, mas tudo bem.

Comment: Para o que você quer, só remover uma chave e criar utra é o suficiente. Outras pessoas buscando a mesma pergunta podem ter um cenário em que precisam da operação atômica, ou querem entender como Python funciona por dentro.