# Como atualizar alguns elementos no SET em Python?

Tags: python

Não são todos os elementos que eu quero atualizar no **SET** apenas **precisa ser mudado o país França para Alemanha**

Meu código está assim:

```
paises = {'França', 'Japão', 'China', 'Brasil', 'Espanha', 
          'USA', 'China', 'Japão', 'USA', 'Tailândia'}

print (paises)
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa trabalhar com sets? Se quiser pode transformar em lista, editar e "retransformar" em set.

Comment: Pelo que eu me lembre, sets são como conjuntos (que seguem a lógica de diagramas de Venn)

Comment: sets evitam a repetição de objetos mostrando-os sem nenhum tipo de ordem

Comment: Exato, mas qual seria seu caso em específico?

Comment: Atualizar elemento **França** para **Alemanha**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um set tem a mesma questão que as chaves de dicionário, como expliquei na sua [outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379874/como-mudar-o-valor-da-chave-em-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-em-python/379892#379892) - não há uma operação atômica para trocar um elemento.

Nesse caso, você realmente precisa chamar dois métodos: um para remover o valor antigo (o método `remove`) e uma outra chamada para adicionar um elemento novo (método `add`)

Faça uma função para fazer isso, e, se for necessário, como no outro caso, você pode sofisticar o código no futuro para evitar conflitos, colocar alguma garantia para multi-threading, etc:

```
def troca_elemento(conjunto, antigo, novo):
     conjunto.remove(antigo)
     conjunto.add(novo)
```

(Como no caso dos dicionários, você pode ou não criar uma nova classe e deixar isso como um método - mas uma funçao vai funcionar igualmente bem).

Conforme completei na outra resposta, se houver absoluta necessidade de que essa operação seja atômica, ou seja: não haver o risco de código em outra thread "enxergar" o set em um estado inconsistente isso é - ou com os dois valores, ou sem nenhum dos dois -  a única forma de fazer isso é criar uma outra classe que responda como um conjunto, e que tenha um thread.Lock na instância para bloquear o acesso enquanto a mudança está em curso. Para isso, a forma mais fácil é herdar essa classe de [`collections.abc.MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSet) e verificar o lock nos métodos implementados. (Nesse caso, a troca deve ser implementada como um método da classe também).

Pode soar complicado, mas é simples (o código fica grande, mas é a mesma estratégia em cada um dos métodos obrigatórios):

```
from collections.abc import MutableSet
from threading import Lock

class AtomicSet(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self._data = set(*args, **kw)
    def exchange(self, old_value, new_value):
        with self.lock:
            self._data.remove(old_value)
            self._data.add(new_value)
    def __contains__(self, value):
        with lock:
            return value in self._data
    def __iter__(self):
        with lock:
            yield from iterself._data
    def __len__(self):
        with lock:
            return len(self._data)
    def add(self, value):
        with lock:
            self._data.add(value)
    def discard(self, value):
        with lock:
            self._data.discard(value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Atomic{self._data!r}"
```