# Como atualizar uma fatia da chave (key) de um dicionário em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, dicionário, scraping

Como faço para atualizar apenas uma fatia de uma chave em um dicionário Python? Estou fazendo o scraping de uma página e gostaria de formatar o resultado de modo que a minha chave fique na mesma linha que o meu valor, por exemplo:

Air Conditioners: https://www.consumerreports.org/cro/air-conditioners.htm

Como há tags "\n" no meu dicionário (por exemplo: {'\nAir Conditioners\n': '/cro/air-conditioners.htm'...}), quando eu printo esse resultado, a chave fica em uma linha diferente do meu valor. Por isso estou tentando remover só os dois últimos caracteres das minhas chaves. Tentei substituir o "\n" do final da chave por "", reatribuindo a variável key, mas não obtive sucesso. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso? Segue o código abaixo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def leia_arquivo():
    arquivo = open('43.consumer_reports.txt')
    dado = file.read()
    arquivo.close()
    return dado


soup = BeautifulSoup(leia_arquivo(), 'lxml')


produtos = {}   # {nome do produto: link do produto}
produtos = {a.string: a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='products-a-z__results__item')}
print(produtos)

for key, value in produtos.items():
    if key[-2:] == '\n':
        key = key.replace('\n', '')
    print(produtos)
    print(f'{key}: https://www.consumerreports.org{value}')
```

Tentei usar os métodos dessa resposta: [Como mudar o valor da chave em um dicionário em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379874/como-mudar-o-valor-da-chave-em-um-dicion%c3%a1rio-em-python) , mas nãoa obtive sucesso também, talvez porque se trate de um fatiamento e não de uma substituição ou remoção total da chave.

Comment: Eu marquei como duplicada, pq. a minha resposta na pergunta indicada explica bem o que acontece para renomear chaves de dicionário, e dá as opções. Mas nesse caso aí, a melhor coisa é remover os espaços em branco (todos os caracteres da categoria espaço), na hora de criar o dicionário  a primeira vez. O método `.strip()` de strings faz isso - é só re-escrever a sua linha que cria o dicionário como: `produtos = {a.string.strip(): a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='products-a-z__results__item')}`

Comment: (a linha acima dessa, criando um dicionário vazio também é desnecessária - a dict-comprehension, como você está usando já cria um novo dicionário)

Comment: @jsbueno muito obrigada pelas correções e pela ajuda. Era mais simples do que eu estava pensando. Devo excluir essa questão?

Comment: Pode deixar ela por aí - acaba sendo uma outra forma das pessoas acharem a questão que tem a resposta correta.